# Setup buildroot for old kernels

Tags: linux, makefile, kernel, cross-compiling, buildroot

I'm trying to setup buildroot for cross-compiling a custom app.

```
/ # uname -a
Linux Venus 2.6.12.6-VENUS #323634 Wed May 25 13:40:36 CST 2011 mips unknown
```

So far I chose kernel version *2.6.12.6* in buildroot. Now I've got the problem that the `make` command fails yelling that the rule `headers_install` is unknown.

Here is the compleat output:

```
~/buildroot-2011.11$ make
(cd /root/buildroot-2011.11/output/toolchain/linux-2.6.12.6; \
         /usr/bin/make -j2 ARCH=mips \
                HOSTCC="/usr/bin/gcc" HOSTCFLAGS="" \
                HOSTCXX="/usr/bin/g++" \
                INSTALL_HDR_PATH=/root/buildroot-2011.11/output/toolchain/linux headers_install; \
        )
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/buildroot-2011.11/output/toolchain/linux-2.6.12.6'
Makefile:485: .config: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
make[1]: *** Keine Regel, um »headers_install« zu erstellen.  Schluss.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/buildroot-2011.11/output/toolchain/linux-2.6.12.6'
make: *** [/root/buildroot-2011.11/output/toolchain/linux/.configured] Fehler 2
```

I think the problem is that this old kernel doesn't have this option in its makefile.

My next try was to use the Makefile and the scripts directory of the new kernel 3.2.6 by replacing the old one.

Here is the output:

```
# make
(cd /root/buildroot-2011.11/output/toolchain/linux-2.6.12.6; \
         /usr/bin/make -j2 ARCH=mips \
                HOSTCC="/usr/bin/gcc" HOSTCFLAGS="" \
                HOSTCXX="/usr/bin/g++" \
                INSTALL_HDR_PATH=/root/buildroot-2011.11/output/toolchain/linux headers_install; \
        )
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/buildroot-2011.11/output/toolchain/linux-2.6.12.6'
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
  HOSTCC  scripts/unifdef
Makefile:1059: *** Headers not exportable for the mips architecture.  Schluss.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/buildroot-2011.11/output/toolchain/linux-2.6.12.6'
make: *** [/root/buildroot-2011.11/output/toolchain/linux/.configured] Fehler 2
```

No idea what I can try now. What should I do?

Comment: The simplest thing would probably be to switch to an older version of Buildroot.

Comment: Hi ekire, I faced with same issue, I need to build mipsel toolchain based on kernel 2.6.10. Did you managed to bypass this issue? I would appreciate any information...

Comment: No I just dropped that project. I switched to a RaspberryPi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All modern tools that build cross-compilation toolchains rely on the kernel implementing the `headers_install` target. So as suggested by Shawn, you can try with an older Buildroot version, but I think we have been using exclusively `headers_install` since quite a long time, so you would have to go way back in the past, and face many other problems.

What about upgrading your kernel instead?

Comment: *"you can try with an older Buildroot version"* -- Early versions of Buildroot (e.g. 20070706) do not have the capability to build the Linux kernel; it just does as its name implies: build a root filesystem. Buildroot-20080424 can compile the Linux kernel, but only going back to 2.6.20.

Comment: *"What about upgrading your kernel instead?"* - this suggestion is a non-starter in the general case for embedded systems with proprietary IP hardware such as a baseband radio, video-over-IP, network processor and similar. These systems are often sold with proprietary firmware and other binary blobs that  require significant vendor support in order to upgrade the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

If you use toolchain from scratch with buildroot, you may custom the header files of toolchain, then custom kernel to match the toolchain, that's would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You must replace **headers_install** with **install** in file:

> package/linux-fusion/linux-fusion.mk

There is line

> $(TARGET_CONFIGURE_OPTS) $(MAKE) $(LINUX_FUSION_MAKE_OPTS) INSTALL_MOD_PATH=$(STAGING_DIR) -C $(@D) **headers_install**

Found [here](http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/buildroot/2010-July/036132.html).